# Test case is not executing as per as order define of Test Class name in TestNG xml

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have created Class1 and Class2 and so on....., In Each Test-Case Class , set the priority of the Testcase from 0 to 1,2,3,4,5 ...... Using POM as project architecture.

```java
  ClassTest() {
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void verifytest1 () {
    }
    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void verifytest2 () {
    }
    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void verifytest3 () {
    }
  }

  ClassTest2() {
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void verifytest1 () {
    }
    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void verifytest2 () {
    }
    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void verifytest3 () {
    }
  }
```

In Testng xml file

```xml
    <test name="CMS Test Cases" preserve-order="true" enabled="true" parallel="none">
            <classes>
                <class name="ClassTest1" />
                <class name="ClassTest2" />
                        ....
                    ....
                    ....
                <class name="ClassTestn" />
            </classes>

        </test>
```

The above define in Testng, when running the test Suite, it runs random class. When it runs random the sequences of the testcase which should executes earlier is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use groups and dependencies. Here is example

```
<test name="My suite">
  <groups>
    <dependencies>
      <group name="c" depends-on="a  b" />
      <group name="z" depends-on="c" />
    </dependencies>
  </groups>
</test>
```

Source: https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-testng-xml